# I am trying to use pdfjs viewer ver. pdfjs-4.0.379-dist and while running it on XAMPP server i get this error:

Tags: mime-types, pdf.js

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I am not sure if the problem is about using type of "module" for pdf.mjs and viewer.mjs or the path of the files but I did not change any of the default lines within the code I have downloaded from https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

I tried to import the func. used inside both files in the viewer.html but the same error it is